# If $\vec a$ and $\vec b$ are any two unit vectors, find the greatest positive integer in the range of $\dfrac{3|\vec a+\vec b|}2+2|\vec a-\vec b|$.

Tags: trigonometry, vectors, contest-math

The following question is taken from JEE exam practice questions.

> If $\vec a$ and $\vec b$ are any two unit vectors, find the greatest positive integer in the range of $\dfrac{3|\vec a+\vec b|}2+2|\vec a-\vec b|$.

**My Attempt:**

Let $$\dfrac{3|\vec a+\vec b|}2+2|\vec a-\vec b|=k$$

Squaring, $$\frac{9(1+1+2\cos\theta)}4+4(1+1-2\cos\theta)+6|(\vec a^2-\vec b^2)|=k^2\\\implies18+18\cos\theta+32-32\cos\theta=4k^2\\\implies50-4k^2=14\cos\theta\\\implies-14\le50-4k^2\le14\\\implies-64\le-4k^2\le-36\\\implies9\le k^2\le16$$

So, my answer is $4$ but the given answer is $5$.

**What's wrong in my approach?**

Comment: What are $\vec a^{2}$ and $\vec b^{2}$? $|\vec a -\vec b| |\vec a +\vec b|$ is not $0$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy they are both $1$, so, their subtraction is zero?

Comment: No! Do not treat vectors like numbers.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy oh I thought $|\vec a+\vec b||\vec a-\vec b|=|(\vec a+\vec b)(\vec a-\vec b)|$. Is this step correct?

Comment: Products and squares of vectors do not make sense.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy thanks, in that case, how do we solve $|\vec a+\vec b||\vec a-\vec b|$?

Comment: Note that if the vectors are orthogonal the expression is just under $5$ (it's exactly $\frac {7\sqrt 2}2$).  That should have been one of the first examples you tried.  Note that this is not the max, though it is close.

Comment: @lulu thanks...

Answer (score 1):

Since $\vec{a},\vec{b}$ are unit vectors, let $\theta$ be the angle between them, then

$| \vec{a} + \vec{b} | = 2 \cos \dfrac{\theta}{2} $

and

$ | \vec{a} - \vec{b} | = 2 \sin \dfrac{\theta}{2} $

Hence, the function we want to maximize is

$ y = 3 \cos \dfrac{\theta}{2} + 4 \sin \dfrac{\theta}{2} $

Clearly, the maximum of $y$ is $\sqrt{3^2 + 4^2} = 5 $

Comment: Hi, thanks. Can we conclude with the method that I began with?

Comment: I don't think the expressions you wrote are correct.  Anyway I leave that to you, if you want to follow it.